# Can't access phpMyAdmin, neither open website on localhost (Wordpress)

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost

So I'm doing my internship right now, I was about to be done with my website, and upload it. It is Wordpress, I wanted to upload it by using Duplicator. It failed, so I manually moved the files to my host and zipped the database only.

When I wanted to install it, I forgot the password to the root, so I changed it. It still denied access, so I wanted to go through C-panel, but I forgot the password there too, so I changed it, also. But it still denied access.

I wanted to open my website on my localhost, it said:

> Error establishing database connection.

Then I went to phpMyLogin, trying to change the password again, and clicked on an option that No password, hoping that would solve the issue. Now I cannot even access phpMyAdmin anymore, I get this error:

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

If it try without password:

> Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)

Can somebody help me with this, please? My whole project is done, this is very frustrating.

Comment: Sorry, but this is all very confusing. We cannot help with your password issues. You need to know what you are doing, your post currently reads as if you are trying around. That is not how computer science is done. Apart from that: what do you mean by "and zipped the database only"? What did you but into a `zip` archive and what did you do with that afterwards?

Comment: As an intern, you should have a supervisor who can assist you with this sort of thing. Randomly flailing around with password resets isn't the best approach to troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Go to cPanel, create a new database and user.  [image]

After that, from MySQL Databases go to **Add User To Database** and give necessary permission

[image]

[image]

Then update the wp-config.php file with database and user parameters. For your reference, I have given you the parameters

/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', '');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

After that also check .htaccess file.